# How to count the amount of swaps made in insertion sort?

Tags: python, insertion-sort

I'm trying to count the amount of times Insertion Sort makes a swap, or sorts a value in an array. Where should I increment the swap count?

This is on Python 3, and I've tested several indentations, with none of them seeming to work. Additionally, to no avail, I've looked for answers on various websites including stack overflow.

```py
def insertionsort(array):
    swapsmade = 0
    checksmade = 0
    for f in range(len(array)):
        value = array[f]
        valueindex = f
        checksmade += 1
        # moving the value
        while valueindex > 0 and value < array[valueindex-1]:
            array[valueindex] = array[valueindex-1]
            valueindex -= 1
            checksmade += 1
        swapsmade += 1 #  FIX THIS
        array[valueindex] = value
    print(array)
    swapsnchecks = "{} swaps were made. {} checks were made.".format(swapsmade, checksmade)
    return swapsnchecks
```

The issue with how I've placed the counter arises when I use a sorted list with, for instance, ten integers (i.e. `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]`). I expected the output to be `0 swaps were made. 55 checks were made.`, but the output ends up being `10 swaps were made. 55 checks were made.`

Comment: With your given input, `0 swaps were made. 55 checks were made.` is incorrect. It should be 0 swaps, 10 checks. If you're getting 10, 55 then you're most likely inserting your list backwards, in which case 45,55 is correct. And of course the answer below is correct as well, about the indentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to indent your counter inside the while loop as follows:

```
def insertionsort(array):
    swapsmade = 0
    checksmade = 0
    for f in range(len(array)):
        value = array[f]
        valueindex = f
        checksmade += 1
        # moving the value
        while valueindex > 0 and value < array[valueindex-1]:
            array[valueindex] = array[valueindex-1]
            valueindex -= 1
            checksmade += 1
            swapsmade += 1 #  Move inside the while loop
        array[valueindex] = value
    print(array)
    swapsnchecks = "{} swaps were made. {} checks were made.".format(swapsmade, checksmade)
    return swapsnchecks
```

For example:

```
print(insertionsort([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))
print(insertionsort([2, 1, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]))
print(insertionsort([10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]))

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
0 swaps were made. 10 checks were made.
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
1 swaps were made. 11 checks were made
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
45 swaps were made. 55 checks were made.
```

Comment: Figured it out. OP is inputting the list backwards, so 10 swaps and 55 checks was correct...

Comment: Scratch that, 45 swaps!